# How to add an icon to canvas in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, android-jetpack

I am trying to add and icon from resource in `Canvas` `DrawScope`.
The nearest solution I found is `drawImage()`, but it doesn't work for my case. Also I cannot use the normal `Icon()` composable inside the `DrawScope`. So is there any work around to display an icon inside canvas, similarly to the way we do it with composable:

```
import androidx.compose.material.Icon

Icon(Icons.Rounded.Menu, contentDescription = "Localized description")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Icons.Rounded.Menu` is a `VectorImage` and you can wrap it into a `VectorPainter`.
You can use something like:

```
val painter = rememberVectorPainter(Icons.Rounded.Menu)
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    with(painter) {
        draw(painter.intrinsicSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this way, but is it possible to many any modifications to the icon(like change color, size etc. )

Comment: the draw method has the size, alpha and colorFilter parameters

Answer (score 1):

Drawscope extension for abstract class Painter has size, alpha and colorFilter params. You can change these params. If you wish to change draw position of Icon, it' drawn top left (0,0) by default you can use translate function or other functions such as rotate or scale for further operations

```
val painter = rememberVectorPainter(Icons.Rounded.Menu)
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    translate(left = 0f, top = 0f) {
        with(painter) {
         //   draw(size = painter.intrinsicSize)
            draw(
                size = Size(40.dp.toPx(), 40.dp.toPx()),
                alpha = 1f,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Red)
            )
        }
    }
}
```